# Search by field in Lucene

Tags: lucene

Although being a total newbie, may be this question is pretty naive. 
I want to search my index based on the index. So I tried created a document with just one index, Name, and then want to search for that particular field.

I am doing this in process of trying to find out if I can update the fields of a document without actually deleting a document in lucene.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can search for words within a particular field with the colon syntax i.e. `name:john`.

But because a lot of indexes just have one field you are going to want to search on, there is a default field, in case you just search for `john`. You can set which field that is when you instanciate your QueryParser

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "name", anAnalyzer);
Query q = parser.parse("john");
```

If you want to create your queries programmatically rather than parsing a user-entered query string, then you also have to specify the field explicitly, for example:

```
Query q = new TermQuery(new Term("name", "john"));
```

Links: [Using fields in Lucene queries (Lucene Query Syntax)](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Fields) | [QueryParser Javadoc](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.html) | [TermQuery Javadoc](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/TermQuery.html)

Answer (score 0):

> I am doing this in process of trying to find out if I can update the fields of a document without actually deleting a document in lucene.

I do not understand the first question, but you cannot update a document in Lucene. You have to delete and re-insert.

Comment: Hi Thilo, I just want to search my index by field. For example, I want to get the value of a particular field[say Name] in my index. Usually you do that by Document.getField("Name") if you know the document but I am not able to get it working while searching the index.

Comment: Document.getField will only work if the field is STORED (and not just INDEXED).